# Why are enums considered compound types?

Tags: c++, enums, types

Arrays, functions, pointers, references, classes, unions, enumerations and pointers to members are *compound types*.

My understanding of a compound type is that is based on other type(s). For example, `T[n]`, `T*` and `T&` are all based on `T`. Then what other type(s) is an enumeration based on?

Or if my understanding of compound types is incorrect, what exactly is it about a type that makes it a compound type? Is *compound* simply a synonym for *user-defined*?

Comment: In C, the term "derived type" instead of "compound type" is used instead, and in C enums are not derived types. This makes me think that "compound type" in C++ is not only meant to compound types to a new type, but also values to a new type. The description of enumerations given hardens that suspicions which says "enumerations, which comprise a set of named constant values."

Comment: @Johannes enums in C and enums in C++ are quite different beasts, aren't they? For example, you can assign integral values to enum variables in C but not in C++.

Comment: correct but nontheless in both languages they define an own type. But i guess i'm interpreting too much into these two terms. "compound type" in fact seems to only refer to the action of compounding types, and the underlying type like AndreyT says for enums is the type compounded, it seems :)

Comment: It's a bit sad that the standard introduces terms like "compound types" without *motivating* them. Maybe someone has the Annotated Reference Manual and can look it up? That would be nice.

Comment: the ARM uses the term "derived type" and doesn't include enumerations likewise. It seems that this term was motivated by the fact that "derived" has got a different meaning in C++ (classes derived from other classes). However i think you have a good point. The closeness of C to the underlying integer type (to which it even is compatible) maybe motivated them not to make enumerations derived types, and reversely motivated the C++ designers to make them compound types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In C++ enum types are *scalar* types, yet at the same time they are compound types since they are built on top of some fundamental integral type. In case of an array or pointer you specify "base" type explicitly, but in case of an enum the specific underlying integral type is chosen implicitly and automatically by the implementation. You have no manual control over the underlying integral type, which still doesn't disqualify enum types from being compound in nature.

Some compilers (as well as future C++ standard C++0x) allow user to specify the underlying integer type for given enum type, which makes it more obvious that it is in fact a compound type. See [here](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#enum) for examples like

```
enum class Color : char { red, blue };
```